# Hooks in login page gives error localhost redirected you too many times

Tags: codeigniter

I am getting error -
localhost redirected you too many times.
in hooks 
This is my code in hooks.I am unable to resolve this issue please help me
and please explain how to use hooks in ci and i am using post_controller_constructor

```
<?php
    class Example {  

        private $CI;

        function __construct()
        {
            $this->CI =& get_instance();

            if(!isset($this->CI->session)){  //Check if session lib is loaded or not
                  $this->CI->load->library('session');  //If not loaded, then load it here
            }

            //echo "class".$this->CI->router->class; die;

            if (  $this->CI->router->class  == 'student' )
            {
                return;
            }


        }

        public function check_login()  
        {
             echo $session_userdata = $this->CI->session->userdata('email');
             echo "session data".$session_userdata;
           //  die;
            if(empty($session_userdata)) {
                redirect("student/index");
            }
            else {
                echo "here";
            }
        }  
    }
    ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

i'm guessing your hook array looks like

```
$hook['post_controller_constructor'] = array(
    array(
        'class' => 'Example',
        'function' => 'check_login',
        'filename' => 'Example.php',
        'filepath' => 'hooks'
    ),
);
```

It doesn't really matter whether you return anything in your constructor or not - a constructor serves only one purpose - to instantiate their respective class.

So basically you have to do something like

```
class Example {  

    private $CI;

    function __construct()
    {
        $this->CI =& get_instance();

        if(!isset($this->CI->session)){  //Check if session lib is loaded or not
              $this->CI->load->library('session');  //If not loaded, then load it here
        }
    }

    public function check_login()  
    {
         echo $session_userdata = $this->CI->session->userdata('email');
         echo "session data".$session_userdata;
       //  die;
        if(empty($session_userdata) && $this->CI->router->class !== 'student') {
            redirect("student/index");
        }
        else {
            echo "here";
        }
    }  
}
```

Comment: whats your url and try to print out `echo $this->CI->router->class` before your `die` and comment that out.

Comment: $this->CI->router->class gives me student

Answer (score 0):

First of all, if you are using hooks in the CodeIgniter for the first time then follow some steps.
**Step1: Enabling Hooks**

The hooks feature can be globally enabled in the application/config/config.php file

Open config.php file does following replaces

```
$config['enable_hooks'] = FALSE;
```

To

```
$config['enable_hooks'] = TRUE;
```

**Step2: Defining a Hook** 
Hooks are defined in the application/config/hooks.php file.

```
$hook['post_controller'] = array(
        'class'    => 'firstHookFile',
        'function' => 'checkHook',
        'filename' => 'firstHookFile.php',
        'filepath' => 'hooks'
);
```

**Step3: Create hook file** 
Create file in the application/hooks.

```
<?php
class firstHookFile
{
  public function checkHook()
  {
      // load the instance
      $this->CI =& get_instance();
      $this->CI->load->helper('uri');
      echo base_url();
      return;
  }
}
?>
```

This hook is only for example purpose, this hook will return the base URL of your project.

I hope you have understood how to use hooks in Codeigniter.